# On minimization images go down from position CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I created this simple blog on react. One large pic and three small pictures on side. It is fine in desktop but when i minimize the main pic works fine but small pictures move down distorting the whole view.

[image]

This. 
[image]

And this on full minimization. 
[image]

I tried playing with postition relative and absolute but no effect.

Please guide

Here is the HTML

```
    <Card>
            <div className='galleryPost'>
                <section style={{width: '70%'}}>
                    <NavLink to={`/post/${nangaparbatStuff.slug}`}>
                    <div>
                        <img src={`${nangaparbatStuff.blogImage}`} alt=''/>
                    </div>
                    </NavLink>
                </section>


                <section className='sideImageWrapper' style={{width: '30%', float: 'right'}}>
                    <NavLink to={`/post/${saralStuff.slug}`}>
                    <div className='sideImageHeight'>
                        <img src={`${saralStuff.blogImage}`} alt=''/>
                    </div>
                    </NavLink>

                    <NavLink to={`/post/${chittakathaStuff.slug}`}>
                    <div className='sideImageHeight'>
                        <img src={`${chittakathaStuff.blogImage}`} alt=''/>
                    </div>
                    </NavLink>

                    <NavLink to={`/post/${sheosarStuff.slug}`}>
                    <div className='sideImageHeight'>
                        <img src={`${sheosarStuff.blogImage}`} alt=''/>
                    </div>
                    </NavLink>
                </section>              
            </div>  
        </Card>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.galleryPost{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
.galleryPost img{
    width: 100%;   
}
sideImageWrapper div{
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.sideImageWrapper img{
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.sideImageHeight{
      height: 235px;
  }
```

Comment: Can you put the code as a working snippet? it's easier to see what's going on

Comment: You can use bootstrap grid to define how the images should be displayed on different resolutions. Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Comment: CSS is pretty meaningless without HTML. Please provide your HTML as well. Preferably as a [mcve]

Comment: Html added to the question

Comment: Did you try my solution? it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Ger yes i want to adjust the right images to fit according to the left in sync

Comment: You have to do it with JavaScript in order to keep the relation although you change the image, but you have to post another question because the css problem has been already solved, the height adjust problem is another problem. When you post the question put the link in the comments so we can help you

Comment: Can you guide me how to do it by javascript? I thought it was a css problem

Comment: Post another question, as you know StackOverflow is a community so your question is going to help others, you can’t combine 2 different problems because it can be confusing, in this question you asked for your css columns problem and not for your height adjustment problem both are different problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207374/discussion-between-ger-and-yahya-rehman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.leftImage{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
}
.rightImages{
  width:30%;
  float:right;
}
.image{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftImage">
  <img class="image" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg"/>
</div>
<div class="rightImages">
  <img class="image" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg"/>
  <img class="image" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg"/>
  <img class="image" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It did work the small images are responsive now but they are getting out of the block. How to fix this? I tried naming them smallImg and fixing the height but that again gives rise to the previous issue. Sorry if i am asking dumb questions but im a beginner 

https://i.ibb.co/Wn7K159/Screenshot-2020-02-06-at-3-23-05-PM.png

Comment: I did try .rightImages img{ height: 235px; } It works initially https://i.ibb.co/5ry8cxs/Screenshot-2020-02-06-at-4-06-51-PM.png but when i strart to minimise it doesnt respond at first so the large image gets small but the three dont. – https://i.ibb.co/WHBbJKq/Screenshot-2020-02-06-at-4-07-23-PM.png & https://i.ibb.co/YRYDbL7/Screenshot-2020-02-06-at-4-08-06-PM.png but then it becomes responsive again https://i.ibb.co/wz2y2cG/Screenshot-2020-02-06-at-4-09-28-PM.png but out of order regardless

Comment: So you want to adjust the right images to fit according to the left? for example if left height is 900 px the others have to be 300 px ?